# How to find what SQL Jobs are using a specific account as Proxy?

Tags: sql-server, security, proxy

We have identified a few servers that are using Proxy accounts inappropriately. Some of these servers have multiple Credentials and Lots of Jobs.  Manually checking the Job Property GUI for "Run As" on each step is not desired.

How can I quickly identify which if any, jobs have steps that are using Proxy Credentials we have identified as inappropriate?

I want to see, the account related to the Proxy. As well as the Job Name and Step the Proxy is used on.

SQL 2008+

Comment: If you go to the proxy properties the references tab will have a list of jobs that use the proxy.

Comment: I don't see it.  Proxies are listed under Instance > Security > Credentials.  I am accessing with SSMS 2014 and all I see is a "General" page.

Comment: Go under SQL Agent -> Proxies -> ProxyType (CMDExec etc) -> The proxy you are interested in

Comment: That works, you should post it as an alternate answer. If you are looking at multiple servers for multiple proxies, the query is quicker, but for random checks the GUI is a viable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The servers I was looking at had only few credentials. While they had several jobs only a handful were using “Run As” Proxy credentials.  This is the solution I used.

First query shows the account (credential identity) linked to the proxy
Second Query shows what Job and Step is using a Proxy

```
    -- Search Credentials (shows account for Name)

    use msdb
    select *
    from sys.credentials

    --Search Jobs where there is a 'Run As' proxy and get the name of that proxy

    use msdb

    select  sysjobsteps.job_id
    , sysjobs.name as 'JobName'
    , sysjobsteps.step_id
    , sysjobsteps.step_name
    , sysjobsteps.subsystem
    , sysjobsteps.last_run_date
    , sysjobsteps.proxy_id
    --, sysjobsteps.step_uid
    , sysproxies.name as 'ProxyName'


    from sysjobsteps
    left join dbo.sysproxies
     on sysjobsteps.proxy_id = sysproxies.proxy_id
    left join dbo.sysjobs
     on sysjobsteps.job_id = sysjobs.job_id

    where sysjobsteps.proxy_id > 0
```

I tried a couple of ways of joining sys.credentials to dbo.sysproxies. If there was more than one credential it did not work well. Separate quires met my needs so I did not dwell on the join.

Comment: You should be able to join sys.credentials.credential_id to dbo.sysproxies.credential_id.  Did this not work?

Comment: It did join but if there was more than one credential it only brought back the bottom record from sys.credential, I was joining with the name field. It showed others as null.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the GUI to do a quick check on all jobs using a single proxy.

In object explorer navigate to the proxy

[image]

Right click on the proxy and select properties.  Then go to the references tab.

[image]

That will list all jobs/job steps that use a given proxy.

Obviously a query is better for mass checks but this works for spot checks.